# Index $variable undefined al enviar variable de ajax a php mediante post

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

aquí les dejo el código:

```
$("#ajax_formulario").submit(function () {
    $.post("ajax.php", {nombre:$(".ajax_nombre").val(), apellido:$(".apellido_ajax").val(), edad:$(".edad_ajax").val() }, function () {
          alert("Exitos al enviar los datos");
    });
});
```

Este es el código JS, usando el `$.post` para que se envíe mediante post al php *ajax.php*; empaquetando las variables y luego una función anónima, en php las recibo así:

```
<?php

    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
    $edad = $_POST["edad"];


    echo $nombre + $apellido + $edad;
?>
```

pero me sale el error de

> index $nombre undefined

al igual con la edad y apellido.

Comment: añade el html que estas usando

Comment: tus div con las clases(ajax_nombre, apellido_ajax y edad_ajax) estan llegando con algun valor y estan escritas correctamente?

Comment: @Shum te agregué una respuesta espero te sirva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente de tu ejercicio, si bien estas tomando en JavaScript los valores de tus cajas de texto, el error que te aparece de PHP es por que a el le estas indicando que le van allegar 3 valores en forma de nombre, edad y apellido y así no se llaman.

> 1. AJAX no te va a funcionar como lo tienes por que en tu form tienes la etiqueta de action indicando a donde se procesará
> 2. el button que estas usando para procesar tu petición tiene el tipo de submit, el cual por defecto su comportamiento es recargar la página
>      completa

Es decir las etiquetas de tus inputs deben ser así

```
<input type="text" name="edad">
```

> También te comento lo ideal es que si estás tomando valores únicos no
>   apliques una etiqueta de clase y en su lugar uses la etiqueta de id

Te dejo un ejemplo similar a lo que buscas en tu ejercicio aplicando AJAX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="ajax_formulario" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label>Nombre:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nombre"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label>apellido:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="apellido"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label>edad:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="edad"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="button" id="enviar"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <div id="resultado"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){
  $('#enviar').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $('#ajax_formulario').serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        $('#resultado').html(data)
      }
    })
  })
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
$edad = $_POST["edad"];


echo $nombre.' '.$apellido.' '.$edad;
```

> Al final como requieres retornar el resultado concatenado en PHP se
>   usa el punto, cuando tu usas el signo de mas estas sumando; entonces
>   te mostrará el error de que dos valores no son numéricos y uno si

Comment: gracias amigo :)

Answer (score 0):

Aqui el formulario:

```
<form id="ajax_formulario" action="ajax.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label>Nombre:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="ajax_nombre"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label>apellido:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="apellido_ajax"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <label>edad:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="edad_ajax"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" id="enviar"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

pon el name a tus formularios así

```
<td><input type="text" name="nombre" class="ajax_nombre"></td>
```

Y para recoger los datos del input , lo haces así

```
 $("input[name='nombre']").val()
```

Creo que tu problema es que estas recogiendo value vacio.

Answer (score 0):

Las variables:

```
{"nombre":$(".ajax_nombre").val(), "apellido":$(".apellido_ajax").val(), 
"edad":$(".edad_ajax").val() }.
```

Seria conveniente ademas invocar los elementos por su id(unica) y no por su clase.

ej:

```
$("#apellido_ajax").val(), y en formulario, id="apellido_ajax"
```